# something wrong when i open the localhost

Tags: django

AttributeError at /
'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.1.7
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:
'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
Exception Location: C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\ecommerce\env\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py, line 26, in process_response
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\ecommerce\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.1
Python Path:
['C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\ecommerce',
'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python39.zip',
'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\DLLs',
'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib',
'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39',
'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\ecommerce\env',
'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\ecommerce\env\lib\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 08 Mar 2021 11:33:27 +0000

Answer (score 1):

Django is trying to access your response like this but it's getting a tuple object instead of a response.

```
if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
```

Have you maybe left a comma in your view when you return the response? Post your views.py if you need more help.

views.py

```
return response,   #remove comma "," here if you have it.
```